# Form Sheet Modal View Animations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` views appearing in my app. Some of them appear from the `Right` some from the `Bottom` and the dismissing seems random. Some disappear to the `Bottom` some go `Left` some go `Up`. Is there a way to set the direction they appear from and dismiss to?

Code I use to present (this same code, just different viewcontroller being presented, called from the same view controller has varying animations for different modal views):

```
MyViewController *newModalView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
newModalView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:newModalView animated:YES];
```

Then in the modal view I call this to dismiss it:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to present them and to dismiss them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and is being worked on by apple.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
newModalView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`. The documentation for that says: When the view controller is presented, its view slides up from the bottom of the screen. On dismissal, the view slides back down. But for me it is not always appearing and disappearing from/to the bottom as I described initially. I have even tried explicitly declaring my `modalTransitionStyle` to be that, but it still have the same odd behavior.

Comment: Yes by doing UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical, it will emerge from the bottom. Try to put an animation instead??

Answer (score 0):

All the transition Styles:

```
newModalView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
newModalView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
newModalView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```